# installation OP5 Monitor / Nagios:

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, nagios, op5

In the case of implementation of the monitoring database oracle control method requires a standard application username and password explicitly. How to bypass the need to enter in clear text password to log into the database oracle, which is visible in the screen OP5 Monitor and Nagios configuration file system.?

Answer (score 4):

There are several possibilities.

**Generic solution**

Use the $USERnn$ macros, which are defined in resources.cfg. More information on how to use this feature: https://kb.op5.com/display/DOC/Macros#Macros-Custommacros
The USER macros are not visible in the graphical user interface, but can be read by anyone having access to the resources.cfg configuration file.
For Naemon documentation on user macros see http://www.naemon.org/documentation/usersguide/macrolist.html#user

**Specific solution for the check_oracle plugin** (if that is what you are using)

Specify the credentials in an auth file. From the help text for the plugin:

```
  -f <auth-file> can be used instead of -u <username> -p <password>. If both
options are used the <auth-file> will override -u/-p. The <authfile> should
be a textfile (readable by the nrpe-user) containing two rows. File format:
username=<username>
password=<password>
```

**Solution specific to OP5 Monitor**

Use custom variables prefixed with OP5SECRET. Unfortunately, these are not very well documented, but take a look at the *Standalone VMware ESXi virtualization host* management pack which uses this feature.

Full disclosure: I work as Development Team Lead at OP5.